# Sentry logs are not correctly showing in production builds

Tags: webpack, next.js, sentry

In development mode, i mean in localhost if I face any exception I get the correct logs [image]

But once the code is pushed or run using npm run build, then it shows the exact error like this

[image]

I'm using Next,js v12 and @sentry/nextjs v7.54

How can I resolve this?